# How to enable/disable hibernate feature on windows 7 at user level

Tags: windows-7, rights

I have two users in my PC. I want my user account to have the Hibernate feature enabled where as I it disabled in the other user. I have tried 
`powercfg -h off` 
with admin mode but disables this feature for all the users.

Also will it free any disk space.

Comment: Hibernation is a system feature, not a user feature. What if two users are logged on, one which wants hibernation enabled and one which wants hibernation disabled?

Answer (score 0):

The Hiberfil.sys hidden system file is located in the root folder of the drive where the operating system is installed. The Windows Kernel Power Manager reserves this file when you install Windows. The size of this file is approximately equal to how much random access memory (RAM) is installed on the computer.

The computer uses the Hiberfil.sys file to store a copy of the system memory on the hard disk when the hybrid sleep setting is turned on. If this file is not present, the computer cannot hibernate.

**To make hibernation unavailable, follow these steps:**

Click Start, and then type cmd in the Start Search box.

In the search results list, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as Administrator.

When you are prompted by User Account Control, click Continue.

At the command prompt, type powercfg.exe /hibernate off, and then press Enter.

Type exit, and then press Enter to close the Command Prompt window..

**To make hibernation available, follow these steps:**
Click Start, and then type cmd in the Start Search box.

In the search results list, right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as Administrator.
When you are prompted by User Account Control, click Continue.

At the command prompt, type powercfg.exe /hibernate on, and then press Enter.

Type exit, and then press Enter to close the Command Prompt window.

I agree with **Raymond Chen** comment. "Hibernation is a system feature, not a user feature."